# What's the difference between these two ways of implementing `on duplication increment`?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

Assume that I have a table `user_count` defined as follows:

```
   id          primary key, auto increment
   user_id     unique
   count       default 0
```

What I want to do is increment `count` by one when an existing record of a user exists or else insert a new record.

Currently, I do it this way (in Python):

```
   try:
      cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user_count (user_id) VALUES (%s)", user.id)
   except IntegrityError:
      cursor.execute("UPDATE user_count SET count = count+1 WHERE user_id = %s", user.id)
```

And it can also be implement this way:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user_count (user_id) VALUES (user_id) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1", user.id)
```

What's the difference between these two ways, and which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is a single SQL command which makes use of the feature that the database offers for solving exactly the problem you have here.

It'd use that as it should be faster and more reliable.

The first one is a fallback if that feature is not available (older database version?).

Answer (score 1):

The first one uses an exception to direct the flow of the program, which isn't what you should do unless you have no other solutions to it (e.g. getting exclusive access to a file). Also, it takes the work from the database which should know better to handle the case.

The second code handles all the work in the database which in turn can optimize the query plan to a very efficient manner.

I would use the second solution as the database usually knows better than yourself how to handle a case.

Comment: +1 - leave exceptions for the exceptions.  and im all for letting databases do what they're good at rather than adding extra conditionals to application code